# jquery 2.1.4 on not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-2.0

What can be possibly wrong in this statement?

```
$(document).on('click',".post_like",function(e) {
    var postId  = $(this).data('id');
    var postOrigin = $(this).data('originalid');
    var interface_type = 'like';

    alert('test');

    //interact_with_post();
    //e.stopPropagation();
});
```

As I'm using jquery 2.1.4 It was expected I could interact with ajax loaded elements but I can`t even click on any element.

PS: it seems that I can't run on() with jquery 1.11.3 on firefox (didn't check other browsers).

**UPDADE**

HTML

```
<div class="panel-footer" style="background:#444; color:#FFF; border-radius:0 0 8px 8px">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-3 text-center" style="border-right: 1px solid #FFF; width:24%; float: left">
<i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i>
<br>
14 hrs ago
</div>
<div class="col-lg-3 text-center **post_like**" style="width:24% float: left ; border-right: 1px solid #FFF" data-originalid="73" data-id="73">
<i id="like_icon73" class="fa fa-heart-o "> </i>
<br>
<normal id="post_like_count73"> 0</normal>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-3 text-center post_comment" left"="" float:="" style="border-right: 1px solid #FFF; width:24%" data-item="73">
<i class="fa fa-comment"></i>
<br>
0
</div>
<div class="col-lg-3 text-center post_unsave" style="width:24% float: left" data-originalid="73" data-id="73">
</div>
</div>
```

So, the idea behind this is , as I'm developing a social networking project, I'm tracking events arround the posts:

I have two functions when something is clicked:

In this case when class post is clicked ( the parent class ) it runs a (study) function that looks at the part was clicked (comment, save, like , open modal , and so on ) and stores the info - intented to study behaviours . At the same time it runs a rewarding function (intended to make them interact) - this function does this: if the user clicked like, add 1 to the like count of the post, changes the class to post_unlike and changes the icon.

Everything works like charm with on("click", function(){}); Except I can't track live clicks ( if the class was post_like , even after I changed it to post_unlike, it continues behaving like it is post_like ).

Now, when I run the same function with on('click', 'class', function(){}); I don't even have a response on the terminal. Not on this, not on ajax loaded posts prior window.onload.

When I used live() it worked like a charm.

Comment: Any console errors? Can you include the relevant markup?

Comment: Could you post HTML as well? It kind of looks like you're trying to track clicks on a Facebook Like button or something. A lot of the time those buttons are loaded inside of an iframe and therefore are not accessible unless you run the code from the domain on which the button is being served.

Comment: Sure thing ! Updating with the html markup and the console log

Comment: Just a verification, but you don't really have `post_like**` as the class name of the element do you? Have you inspected the element in question with firebug? Make certain you elements are interpreted as you expect and that you don't have some other element bleeding over on top of the div you want to capture the click on.

Comment: Oh Sorry ! 
LOOOL my mistake ! But no, in the original code I don't have it ( I was making it bold so it was easier for you to read )

Answer (score 0):

This runs just fine for me...(Firefox 38.0.1, Chrome 42.0.2311.152 m, Chrome 43.0.2357.81 m)

```js
$(document).on('click',".post_like",function(e) {
    var postId  = $(this).data('id');
    var postOrigin = $(this).data('originalid');
    var interface_type = 'like';

    alert('test');

    //interact_with_post();
    //e.stopPropagation();
});
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<div class="post_like">Click Me!</div>
```

Comment: @boban984 It is working, but chrome 46 adds some sandboxing logic that won't allow the popup to happen.  Looks like stackoverflow needs to update their logic slightly to allow alerts to happen (add allow-modals keyword).  It has already been reported to SO here: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/297048/add-allow-modals-to-the-sandbox-of-stack-snippets-snippets-are-broken-in-chrome